# 3rd order differential equation with variable coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to do I solve this differential equation?
$$ x^3 u′′′ + x^2 u′′ + x u′= 0. $$
The series solution method is not working in this case.

Comment: one solution is $$u(x)=C$$ $C$ const.

Comment: But there should be 2 more solutions as well

Comment: yes we have additionally $$x\sin(\ln(x))$$ and $$x\cos(\ln(x))$$

Answer (score 1):

Thos is an example of a **Cauchy-Euler equation**.  See [this link to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation) for a solution method in the second-order case.  The same thing works in third order if you can solve the cubic equation for the exponent, which should be possible here.  Be ready to deal with the "complex" case.

Cauchy-Euler equations have a **regular singular point** at zero, so a Maclaurin series as you apparently tried does not generally work.

Answer (score 1):

Start by putting $v=u'$ and dividing through by $x^3$ to get $v''+\frac{v'}{x}+\frac{v}{x^2}=0$.

The $\frac{1}{x}$ suggests putting $v=w(\ln x)$. That kind of substitution is less common, but it can still be useful. The point is that we have $v'=\frac{w'}{x}$ or $w'=xv'$, that is what we need here so that higher derivatives are multiplied by higher powers of $x$.

We have $v'=\frac{w'}{x},v''=\frac{w''}{x^2}-\frac{w'}{x^2}$ so we get $$w''+w=0$$

That is an easy equation for $w$. We solve it to get $$w=A\cos t+B\sin t$$ Remember that $t=\ln x$. So we have $$v=A\cos(\ln x)+B\sin(\ln x)$$

Now we have to integrate that. The obvious thing to try is to differentiate $x\cos(\ln x)$. That gives $\cos(\ln x)-\sin(\ln x)$. Similarly, differentiating $x\sin(\ln x)$ gives $\cos(\ln x)+\sin(\ln(x)$. So we have finally $$u=Cx\cos(\ln x)+Dx\sin(\ln x)+E$$.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Not quite sure what the problem is. Is that clearer?

Comment: @OscarLanzi ? $x\cos(\ln x)$ gives $\cos(\ln x)+x(-\sin(\ln x)\frac{1}{x})=\cos(\ln x)-\sin(\ln x)$

Comment: Ok, now it works.

Comment: Now? I didn't change it!

Comment: Got my functions mixed up when I differentiated the first time.

Answer (score 1):

Considering $$x^3 u′′′ + x^2 u′′ + x u′= 0$$ let us start with $v=u'$ and now $$x^3 v′′ + x^2 v′ + x v= 0$$ Change variable using $x=e^y$ $$\frac {dv}{dx}=\frac {dv}{dy}\frac {dy}{dx}=\frac {1}{x}\frac {dv}{dy}$$  $$\frac {d^2v}{dx^2}=-\frac {1}{x^2}\frac {dv}{dy}+\frac {1}{x ^2} \frac {d^2v}{dy^2} $$ All of this makes $$\frac {d^2v}{dy^2}+v=0$$ which is simple to integrate (at least for $v(y)$).